# I am trying to get it to print something from a file and it's printing this wierd stuff

Tags: c++

My assignment is to calculate the average grade for a student and have it printed out when the computer is prompted. The problem is that my code prints out only the name Mary and some 0's and 0x6022320.

The file where the grades come from reads:

```
Mary Smith 10  5  8  10  6  2  10
Ken Lewis 5  3  2  10  8  9  10
```

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

string studentnames_array[2];
int studentgrades_array[2][7];
char studentfinal_array[2];

void get_grade();
void compute_grade();
void displaygrade(int b);

int main()

{
get_grade();
compute_grade();

 for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
  {displaygrade(i);}


return 0;

}




void get_grade()
{
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("infile.txt");

for(int a=0;a<2; a++)
{
myfile >> studentnames_array[a] >> studentgrades_array[a][0] >> studentgrades_array[a][1] >> studentgrades_array[a][2] >> studentgrades_array[a][3] >> studentgrades_array[a][4] >> studentgrades_array[a][5]>> studentgrades_array[a][6]; 


}

}

void compute_grade()
{
for (int d=0; d<2; d++)
{
  float total = 0;
for (int e=0; e<7; e++)
{
  total = total + studentgrades_array[d][e];
}
studentfinal_array[d] = total/7.0;
}
}


void displaygrade(int b)

{

cout << setw(8) << left << studentnames_array[b]<<"\n";
for (int c=0; c<7; c++) { cout<< "\t\t"<<right<<setw(4)<<studentgrades_array[b][c];
}
cout << setw(6) << studentgrades_array[b] << "\n"; 

}
```

here is my output:

```
Mary
           0           0           0           0           0  0        00x602230

           0           0           0           0           0  0        00x60224c
```

Comment: Your C++ book should explain what `>>` does, when reading from a stream; and you might want to read that chapter again. `>>` into a string reads a single ***word***. Now, ask yourself the following question: how many words is "Mary Smith"?

Comment: Your final output line is printing a pointer because you put `studentgrades_array` where you want `studentfinal_array`.